Numerical approximation of implicit functions
I have an expression $t \equiv t(x)$,
\begin{equation}
t = 2^{-2+\frac{a}{2}} c^{1-\frac{a}{2}} \Gamma\left(-1+\frac{a}{2}, \frac{c}{2} x^2\right)
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma\left(-1+\frac{a}{2}, \frac{c}{2} x^2\right)$ is the incomplete gamma function, and $a,c$ are constants. In general $0<a<1, 0<c<1$, but I chose specific values $a=\sqrt{20/3}, c=4/25$.
I have another expression $f \equiv f(x)$,
\begin{equation}
f = x^{2+2a} e^{c\, x^2 \,/2}.
\end{equation}
I would like to find a way to write $f \propto t^b$ for some power $b$. I am interested in the regime where $x \rightarrow \infty$ or at least $x \gg 1$. Since the function $\Gamma\left(-1+\frac{a}{2}, \frac{c}{2} x^2\right)$ is non-elementary, there is no trivial way to invert this to give $x \equiv x(t)$ such that $f \propto t^b$. So, I am thinking maybe there is a way to have an approximation $f \sim t^b$ and use some numerical technique to achieve this.
I have tried fitting $f(x)$ with $k t^b$ for some parameters $k,b$ in order to force the search of the relation $f(x) \sim t^b$. Although I don't think this is a good way to approximate the relation.
t[a_, c_, x_] := 2^(-2 + a/2) c^(1 - a/2) Gamma[-1 + a/2, c x^2/2]
f[a_, c_, x_] := x^(2 + 2 a) Exp[c x^2/2]
table = Table[Log[f[Sqrt[20/3], 4/25, x], 10], {x, 10, 50, 1}];
fit = FindFit[table, k t^b, {k, b}, t]
{k -> 0.1169332281, b -> -0.4908628423}

I would like to ask for some guidance or some insights on how to execute this.
Edit: To be consistent, I should have chosen $0< a <1$, say $a=1/3$. Although it is still very informative if there is a power-law solution for parameters that go outside the range of the given.

Not exactly what you want, but Asymptotic[(f[x]*t*c)/  (x^(-2 + 2 Sqrt[15])), x -> Infinity] is (*1*) so $f$ grows sub-exponentially with $1/t$ at least.
$$f \propto \frac{x^{-2 + 2 \sqrt{15}}}{c~t}$$ for large $x$. You should probably make sure I copied down the equations correctly though.

@ydd So $f$ behaves like $\sim x^{-2+2\sqrt{15}}/\Gamma(-1+a/2,c x^2/2)$ for large $x$. If there's just a way to express $x^{-2+2\sqrt{15}}$ in terms of $t^b$ for some power $b$, then everything will be good, ugh! Very nice analysis BTW.

@mathemania Please provide your Mathematica code

@UlrichNeumann I have posted a brief code where I tried to fit $f(x)$ with $k t^b$ for some power $b$. Although I don't think this is a good way since it is much better that there's some explicit relation coming from approximation . My interest is in the region $x \rightarrow \infty$. I was hoping maybe there's some way to find a good approximation to this like the analysis of ydd which gave some insight on the behavior of $f$ and $t$ in the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$, although there is still some $x$ in the numerator.

If you allow $\log{t}$ in your approximation, we can have
$$f \propto \frac{\left(-\frac{2 \log (t)}{c}\right)^{\frac{3 
a}{2}-1}}{c~t}$$
But this is kind of cheating because $\log t$ cannot be expressed as a finite power series of $t$. same notebook here but with additional stuff

@ydd Personally, the point I took from your first comment (actually from the exponential factors in the individual asymptotics of each of f and t at infinity) is that it is impossible to get x in terms of t^b for some power b.

@mathemania From above comments by ydd it follows that there is no $b$ such that $f/t^b$ had finite nonzero limit as $x\to\infty$. What do you want then?

@RomaLee What I'm thinking is that maybe there are some approximations that can be done, probably in the asymptotic limit maybe we can drop some terms or factors, such that the approximate behavior is correct up to some error.

@mathemania Obvious solution approach InverseSeries[  Series[2^(-2 + a/2) c^(1 - a/2) Gamma[-1 + a/2, c x^2/2], {x,     Infinity, 1}], t] unfortunately doesn't work in Mathematica v12.2 (error message  $RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of 25/4+O[1/x]^2.)

@UlrichNeumann I've tried replacing Gamma with its asymptotic form and it returned InverseSeries[Exp[(-c x^2)/2 + O[1/x]^2] x^(-4+a)/c, t] with no error but no result either .

@UlrichNeumann Maybe there's a way to approximately solve for $x=x(t)$, I saw an answer by a user yesterday but somehow the answer was deleted. That user used the asymptotic form of Gamma then used that to invert the equation assuming you plug in the values of a,c. Before I can finish reading the answer it was deleted.

@mathemania I also didn't understand why the answers were deleted.

@UlrichNeumann My answer was based on the impossibility of getting the form desired by the OP and showed an alternative approach, a pretty good one, too. The OP shortly after I posted updated the Q with values for the parameters and ignored my answer. That was followed by another user harassing me for the trivial reason of not using the values in the (updated) Q. The OP having shown no interest and myself wanting to avoid further harassment, I deleted. I liked the practical side of my answer: how to get a good result without being mathematically perfect at each step.

@MichaelE2 Thanks for your response. Your answer looked interesting to me, I was just taking a bit of time trying to understand every step of your answer. It's unfortunate that you have to remove your answer because of the said incident. I truly appreciated your effort including your side comment about the Lambda function discussion in your class.

@MichaelE2 Thanks for your reply. I' ll study your deleted answer with interest in detail. I also often experience similar harassment, but it's not worth spoiling your enjoyment of math because of it

@UlrichNeumann. mathemania, Here is a copy of the markdown of my answer, with some extra tips thrown in about the solution method: https://pastebin.com/Zx2Q5sA1 -- If it works for you, let me know. If nothing else, my students would probably appreciate knowing that someone else out in the world found such stuff useful. :)

@MichaelE2 Did your special course “Lambert function” possibly also solve the equation Exp[d x]==a (x-b)(x-c)?

@UlrichNeumann No. If it could be solved (by Mma, at least), then this special case without parameters should be solved: Exp[u] == u^2-1. And Reduce[E^u == u^2 - 1, u] does not solve. Beware, Reduce[E^u == u^2 - 1, u, Reals] does give a solution, but I believe it does it by first bounding the solution with a concrete interval, which allows it to construct Root[] solutions. Reduce[E^u == u^2 - b^2, u, Reals] returns to failure, even if you include the bound -b - 1/b < u < -b. Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2309691 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999

@MichaelE2 Thanks for your help. Difficult subject matter to understand

to long for a comment, perhaps an answer:
asymptotics of 2^(-2 + a/2) c^(1 - a/2) Gamma[-1 + a/2, c x^2/2], x->Infinity:
tasy=Asymptotic[2^(-2 + a/2) c^(1 - a/2) Gamma[-1 + a/2, c x^2/2], x->Infinity]
(*(E^(-((c x^2)/2)) x^(-4 + a))/c*)

tasy tends to zero as x->Infinity:
Limit[tasy,x->Infinity]  (*ConditionalExpression[0, a \[Element] Reals && c > 0]*)

The asymptotic equation  can be solved for x( c>0):
solx=Solve[tasy==t,x]
(*{{x -> -((I Sqrt[-4 + a] Sqrt[ProductLog[-((c (c t)^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 +a))]])/Sqrt[c])}, 
{x -> (I Sqrt[-4 + a] Sqrt[ProductLog[-((c (c t)^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a))]])/Sqrt[c]}}*)

solx contains two solutions, which get real if a<4:
Block[{a = Sqrt[20/3] ,
  c = 4/25}, 
 zw = Table[{t, Re [Evaluate[x /. solx]]}, {t, 
    Range[0.001, 1, .001]} ] ;
 Show[{ListPlot[Map[{#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]} &, zw], PlotStyle -> Blue], 
   ListPlot[Map[{#[[1]], #[[2, 2]]} &, zw], PlotStyle -> Red]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {t, x}]
 ]


The blue line shows x[t] QP asked for!
modified
power series around t=0 ( Thanks @Mariusz Iwaniuk for his helpful comment) only exists for a>4 (Contrary to the claim a<4 )
    Series[x /. solx, {t, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {c > 0, a > 4}]
    (*

    {-I Sqrt[(-4 + a)/c]
       Sqrt[-((c^(1 + 2/(-4 + a)) t^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a)) - (
       c^(2 + 4/(-4 + a)) t^(4/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a)^2 - (
       3 c^(3 + 6/(-4 + a)) t^(6/(-4 + a)))/(2 (-4 + a)^3)], 
     I Sqrt[(-4 + a)/c]
       Sqrt[-((c^(1 + 2/(-4 + a)) t^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a)) - (
       c^(2 + 4/(-4 + a)) t^(4/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a)^2 - (
       3 c^(3 + 6/(-4 + a)) t^(6/(-4 + a)))/(2 (-4 + a)^3)]}

*)

addendum
Knowing ProductLog[z]~Log[z], z->Infinity we can simplify result solx asymptotically a bit more
x^2 /. solx /. ProductLog -> Log // PowerExpand
(*{-(((-4 + a) (I \[Pi] - Log[-4 + a] + Log[c] + (2 (Log[c] + Log[t]))/(-4 + a)))/c),
-(((-4 + a) (I \[Pi] - Log[-4 + a] + Log[c] + (2 (Log[c] + Log[t]))/(-4 + a)))/c)}*)

Result x^2 asymptotically depends on Log[t] (see @Roman's answer too)!

Try: Series[ProductLog[-((c (c t)^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a))], {t, 0, 1},   Assumptions -> {0 < c < 1, 0 < a < 1}]. Works fine.?

@MariuszIwaniuk Thanks, I only tried without assumptions and got expressions like ProductLog[-((0^(2/(-4 + a)) c)/(-4 + a))]

@MariuszIwaniuk So, I guess there's really no way for a polynomial approximation as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

@UlrichNeumann Sorry for the confusion. The range for the parameters are $0 < a,c <1$. It seems like from your answer that there's no polynomial approximation within that range?

@UlrichNeumann Although it is still fruitful to know that your answer is well-defined for $a>4$, but I don't see that the solution can be written as a power-law.

@Mathemania Yes, only the square of the asymptotic solution x is in the form of power law.

@Mathemania I corrected   my answer. Real solution exists if a<4!

tl;dr – I don't think it's possible.
t[a_, c_, x_] = 2^(-2 + a/2) c^(1 - a/2) Gamma[-1 + a/2, c x^2/2];
f[a_, c_, x_] = x^(2 + 2 a) Exp[c x^2/2];

For $x\to\infty$ the value of $t$ is positive and very small:
q[x_] = Asymptotic[t[a, c, x], x -> ∞] // PowerExpand // FullSimplify
(*    (E^(-((c x^2)/2)) x^(-4 + a))/c    *)

From this asymptotic relationship we find an approximation for $x(t)$: renaming $\tau=t$ in order to avoid a symbol collision,
Solve[q[x] == τ, x] // FullSimplify
(*    {{x -> -((I Sqrt[-4 + a] Sqrt[ProductLog[-((c (c τ)^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a))]])/Sqrt[c])},
       {x -> (I Sqrt[-4 + a] Sqrt[ProductLog[-((c (c τ)^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a))]])/Sqrt[c]}}    *)

We pick the positive solution:
ξ[a_, c_, τ_] = -((I Sqrt[-4 + a] Sqrt[ProductLog[-((c (c τ)^(2/(-4 + a)))/(-4 + a))]])/Sqrt[c]);

The function $f$ now becomes
g[a_, c_, τ_] = f[a, c, ξ[a, c, τ]];

What you want is $g(\tau)\propto\tau^b$. What I find for your specific parameters $a=\sqrt{\frac{20}{3}}$, $c=\frac{4}{25}$, is
$$
g\left(\sqrt{\frac{20}{3}},\frac{4}{25},\tau\right)\approx\frac{25^{\sqrt{15}} \log ^{\sqrt{15}-1}\left(\frac{1}{\tau
   }\right)}{2^{\sqrt{15}+1} \tau}
\text{ as $\tau\to0^+$}.
$$
h[τ_] = (25^Sqrt[15] Log[1/τ]^(Sqrt[15] - 1))/(2^(Sqrt[15] + 1) τ);
With[{a = Sqrt[20/3], c = 4/25},
  Limit[g[a, c, τ] / h[τ], τ -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]
(*    1    *)

So there is an extra logarithmic dependency and a polynomial limit is not possible. Similiar, most likely, for other values of $a,c$.
